# Adding sounds to a multiple-choice quiz using ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a code to make a test of type (multiple choice), and I want to add music to it when the answer is chosen correctly, and another when the choice is made wrong.
However, I could not add the music recall code correctly, and this leads to the music of the wrong choice being heard when the answer is correct, and so on.
Please help in solving the problem and determining the appropriate place to add the music files.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

// matrix of questions
var questions: Array = new Array();
questions[0] = ["The largest freshwater lake in the world", 1];
questions[1] = ["What is the capital of Canada?", 2];
questions[2] = ["The country with the largest gold reserves", 3];
questions[3] = ["The largest car producer in the world", 4];


// answer matrix
var answers: Array = new Array();
answers[0] = ["Huron" , "Victoria" , "Superior" , "Michigan"];
answers[1] = ["Victoria" , "Edmonton" , "Ottawa" , "New Brunswick"];
answers[2] = ["Germany" , "USA" , "Italia" , "France"];
answers[3] = ["Germany" , "Japan" , "USA" , "China"];

//  matrix of correct answers
var rightAnswers: Array = new Array();
rightAnswers[0] = ["Superior" ];
rightAnswers[1] = ["Ottawa" ];
rightAnswers[2] = ["USA" ];
rightAnswers[3] = ["Germany" ];

//-------------------------
var quesArray: Array = new Array();
var ansArray: Array = new Array();
var rAnsArray: Array = new Array();

var randomPos: int = 0;
for (var k: int = 0; k < questions.length; k++)
{
    randomPos = int(Math.random() * questions.length);
    while (quesArray[randomPos] !=null)
{
    randomPos = int(Math.random() * questions.length);
}
    quesArray[randomPos] = questions[k];
    ansArray[randomPos] = answers[k];
    rAnsArray[randomPos] = rightAnswers[k];

}
//--------------------------------
score.text = "0/" + questions.length;
percent.text = "0%";

var i:uint =0;
var t: uint = 1;

show();
function show(): void
{
   title.text = "question number" +(t);
   q.text = quesArray[i][0];
   ans1.text = ansArray[i][0];
   ans2.text = ansArray[i][1];
   ans3.text = ansArray[i][2];
   ans4.text = ansArray[i][3];
   i++;
   t++;
}

ans1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveNext);
ans2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveNext);
ans3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveNext);
ans4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveNext);

var sc: uint = 0;
function moveNext(e:MouseEvent): void
{
   for (var j: uint = 0; j < rAnsArray.length; j++)
   {
       if (e.currentTarget.text == rAnsArray[j])
       {
           sc++;
           score.text = String(sc) + "/" + String(quesArray.length);
           percent.text = String(Math.round(sc / questions.length * 100)) + "%";
       }
   }        

if (i != quesArray.length)
{
   show();
}
else
{
   ans1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveNext);
   ans2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveNext);
   ans3.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveNext);
   ans4.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, moveNext);
}
```

}

```
//These are the codes you used to invoke the audio recall from the library.I couldn't put it in the right place to function properly
    //var music1Play:Music1 = new Music1();
    //var music1Channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
    //SoundMixer.stopAll();
    // music1Channel = music1Play.play();
//-----------
//var music2Play:Music2 = new Music2();
//var music2Channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
//SoundMixer.stopAll();
//music2Channel = music2Play.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want anything special, just your basic audio playback, here is a very simple one-liner:

```
(new Audio).play();
```

Replace the **Audio** with the sound class (you can assign one in the Library). Lets assume, you have two sounds, and their classes are **GoodSound** and **BadSound** respectively. So, upon correct answer you put the line:

```
(new GoodSound).play();
```

Then upon the wrong answer you call:

```
(new BadSound).play();
```